# Did I negate and simplify the boolean expression correctly?

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

I negated the following boolean expression and just need somebody to tell me if I made any mistakes.

**Expression:**

(A∧B)∨(¬A∧C)

**Negation:**

¬[(A∧B)∨(¬A∧C)] = ¬(A∧B)∧¬(¬A∧C) = (¬A∨¬B)∧(A∨¬C)

**Distributive Law**

p∧(q∨r) = (p∧q)∨(p∧r)

Suppose

p = (¬A∨¬B)

q = A

r = ¬C

Let's apply the distribution law:

(¬A∨¬B)∧A∨(¬A∨¬B)∧¬C = A∧¬B∨¬A∧¬C∨¬B∧¬C

Comment: It is straightforward to check the equivalence of these expressions by creating a truth table for each, and then comparing the truth table to make sure the expressions provide identical output for each of the 2^3 = 8 input combinations. Hint: when applying the distributive law, you forgot to keep a negation. It is impossible that the original expression and its negation both contain the term `(¬A∧C)` which should have warned you. Whether you have “simplified” the expression depends on your definition of simple. While the final expression is in disjunctive normal form, it is longer.

Comment: The negation seems ok, however I'm not too sure about your "simplification" with the distributive law. There might be a typo in your expression : What is the $A$ between the two brackets-terms ? Do you mean multiplication which is the same as an $AND$ ?

Comment: @amon, thank you for spotting the missed negation. I edited my question.

Comment: @Zubzyb, thanks. _Do you mean multiplication which is the same as an  AND?_ Yes, I meant AND